# Which transaction will be prioritised: send or send by approved

Tags: blockchain, gas-price, pending-transactions

Let’s say my address is X and I have 10 USDT there.

Address Y is approved spender of wallet X USDT funds, meaning that address Y can send USDT from address X.

Address Z and W are some other addresses.

And now, 2 transactions are sent simultaneously:

1. Transaction made by X: Send 10 USDT from X to Z
2. Transaction made by Y: Send 10 USDT from X to W

Which will go through?

1. Does it depend only on transactions’ gas price?
2. Does priority fee affect which transaction will go through?
3. What time difference is acceptable in order for them to be simultaneous and in order for transaction no. 2 to fail?
4. Does “simultaneous transactions” mean that they come into same block?

Answer (score 2):

It's generally preferred to ask one question at a time but all of the questions point to the same answer.

There is no concurrency. The transactions execute in a definite order determined by their order in the blocks which is determined by the miners. There is no determinism in the process. Nothing relies on the time they were sent or even the `gasPrice`, but `gasPrice` approximates a "bid" for prioritization.

Every blockchain must deal with the uncertainty about transaction order one way or another. These are the "consensus" algorithms. Their purpose is to establish a canonical transaction order from the ambiguously ordered transactions arriving from a distributed network where latency, the lack of an authoritative time source, distrust, and other challenges exist.

It's not about "the right" order, because no node is in a position to know what "right" would be. It's the order that everyone will agree on, i.e. "consensus".

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried these transactions where “transaction made by Y” (transferFrom) failed with error “invalid opcode”. Both transactions were sent at the same time and the “transaction made by Y” had even higher maxGas than ”transaction made by X” (transfer) which did go through. Why is that?

Comment: In Proof-of-Work consensus, transactions are not necessarily mined in the order you think they should be mined in. There is one constraint enforced by the protocol. Transactions from account X will be mined in the same order as they are signed by X (the nonce). You need to study Proof-of-Work. It's a big topic because there is a paradigm shift involved. Probabilistic, not deterministic.

Comment: So, regarding my example, why transferFrom transaction (transaction made by Y) gets every time “invalid opcode”?